# Recursion to calculate sequence

Tags: c, recursion, sequence

Suppose that the first integer is x. Then we define a[0]=x, the next elements of sequence are calculated as:

```
a[n+1]=a[n]/2   if a[n] is even, and 
a[n+1]=a[n]*3+1 if a[n] is odd. 

The sequence continues till it reach value 1, then stop.
```

It looks like this **75, 226, 113, 340, 170, 85, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1**

This is my code (not using the recursion). *The proplem is that it keeps printing output=1 all the times*. I have checked it but I don't know where I was wrong.
Another question is, which datatype is the best to declare for variable x and array a[] (to minimize to the least capacity ? And how can we do this with recursion ?

```
int main(void)
{
    float a[100];
    int i=0;
    float x;
    printf("Enter the value of x: ");
    scanf("%f",&x);
    a[0]=x;
    printf("\n%f\n",a[0]);
    do{
        if (fmod(a[i],2)==0){
            a[i+1]=a[i]/2;}
        else{
            a[i+1]=a[i]*3+1;        
        }
        i++;
    } while (a[i]!=1);
    printf("The ouput value is:\n");
    for (int j=0;j<i;j++){
        printf("%2.2f\t",a[i]);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a **horrible** idea to use floating-point numbers to solve problems related to integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One part of your problem,

> The proplem is that it keeps printing output=1 all the times

```
printf("The ouput value is:\n");
    for (int j=0;j<i;j++){
        printf("%2.2f\t",a[i]); //<--- use a[j] to print instead of a[i]
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

> The proplem is that it keeps printing output=1 all the times

Of course, since you always output the number after the last one in the array (your program even has undefined behavior).

> Another question is, which datatype is the best to declare for variable x and array a[] (to minimize to the least capacity ?

Both could be an `unsigned long long`, you don't even need an array.

```
char buf[0x100];
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
unsigned long long n = strtoull(buf, NULL, 10);
while (n > 1) {
    printf("%ull\n", n);
    n = n % 2 ? 3 * n + 1 : n / 2;
}
```

Comment: One problem is it will not print last `1`.

Comment: @Rohan That's not a "problem", the last number being one is implicit, you can just add `puts("1");` if you feel it's missing.

Answer (score 3):

You just do all the calculation in a single while loop with recursive way... replace this part of your code...

```
printf("\n%f\n",a[0]);
do{
    if (fmod(a[i],2)==0){
        a[i+1]=a[i]/2;}
    else{
        a[i+1]=a[i]*3+1;        
    }
    i++;
} while (a[i]!=1);
printf("The ouput value is:\n");
for (int j=0;j<i;j++){
    printf("%2.2f\t",a[i]);
}
```

replace it with something like that....

```
    while(a[i] > 1){
     printf("\n%f\n",a[i]);
     if(fmod(a[i],2)==0){
       a[i+1]=a[i]/2;
     }else{
       a[i+1]=a[i]*3+1;        
     }
     i++;
    }
```

I didn't test it but the main idea of recursion for this problem should be something like that if you do not want to use any external function for the calculation.
This recursive way also fixed the always printing 1 problem. As i see you already got your answer about printing 1 all the time in your code. You can use a long int instead of a floating point array. I think this ia a good idea. Then you have to change the code by replacing the array a[i] and a[i+1] to a int variable.

Sorry for my bad english. English is not my native language.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it always prints 1 is you used the wrong variable in your for loop

```
for (int j=0;j<i;j++){
    printf("%2.2f\t",a[i]);
}
```

You should access `a[j]` not `a[i]`. `i` is constant in the loop. You should change it to

```
for (int j=0;j<i;j++){
    printf("%2.2f\t",a[j]);
}
```